# Why sometimes p-value is smaller than the most accurate number that numpy can represent

Tags: python, numpy, p-value

Usually we meet the case that p-value (e.g. 2.3e-99), which is obviously smaller than the most accurate number that python can represent(i.e. machine epsilon).

Could you please explain the phenomenon? How credible is the p-value?

If it is possible, how could we get the number that is small to the e-99 degree?

Comment: Why downvoted? Could these people give some reasons?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I'll point out that 2.3e-99 is not "smaller than the most accurate number that python can represent".  That's not what machine epsilon is.

Comment: Thanks. I'll read the related in detail.

Answer (score 2):

The absolute value 2.3e-99 is not credible since it is floating point arithmetic after all. It also depends on how many steps in-between are involved to calculate this value. However, it is probably credible to generously round it. For example p < 0.00001 or so. There is a great article [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) that might be quite informative in this context.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It is quite common in the field of bioinformatics. A famous example is BLAST that rank is sorted by E-value (often get the number smaller than e-99).I just wonder its credibility.

Comment: I think that it doesn't really matter in this case since every estimate is computed using the same equation. What I mean is: If those values are imprecise I'd would be a systematic error and wouldn't really affect the relative ranking. Also, you would be primarily interested in the Bit-score, right!? The Bitscore tells you about the quality of your alignment whereas the E value just tells you how likely this alignment occurred by chance. I wouldn't ignore the E-value, but I think everything lower 2 e-15 or so can be treated as unlikely and then I would rank the results by bit-score